# Tuning TCP sysctl on centos

Tags: centos, tcp, sysctl

I have website that gets higher tcp timeouts at peak times and slows down bit,
here are few stat graphs

[image]

sysctl config atm:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0
kernel.sysrq = 0
kernel.core_uses_pid = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
kernel.msgmnb = 65536
kernel.msgmax = 65536
kernel.shmmax = 68719476736
kernel.shmall = 4294967296
```

Any idea what I should change/add to config?

Comment: TCP timeouts may not be caused by a kernel issue.  More likely it is something with the application taking too long and causing connections to be abandoned.  You might look at the number of open file handles, that is often a limiting factor on Redhat/CentOS systems.  Can you offer more details about the applications and any complaints from users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess is that you're seeing your network receive buffers fill up, in which case you might want to increase them with the `sys.net.core.netdev_max_backlog` sysctl.

You might be seeing a lot of dropped connections in `TIME_WAIT`, in which case you might want to drop the timeout with `net.ipv4.vs.timeout_timewait`.

Both of these should be identifiable with `netstat`.

Your application's socket buffers might be too small, too; you can bump them up with the `net.core.rmem_max`, `net.core.wmem_max`, and `net.ipv4.tcp_rmem` and `net.ipv4.tcp_wmem`.  This is probably not the case, though, but if you're getting a lot of traffic you might find increasing these socket buffer queue sizes helps you handle the traffic.

Remember to measure before and after you change each value.  I recommend googling for them to understand their behaviour so you can better apply them to your use case.